# Chrome randomly scrolling to middle/lower part of page on load

Tags: html, google-chrome, autofocus

I cannot reproduce this on any browser other than google chrome. Randomly when loading a page it will scroll to 50-75% down the page when it loads it.

There is no JS triggering this.

Worse it is not consistent. Happens most of the time I open the page in a new tag. Happens some of the time when I change urls. Happens very few times on page refresh.

I don't even know how to approach debugging this sort of issue. Has anyone experienced it before? Knows workarounds? Possible causes?

It is definitely not the "scrolls to iframe" problem because I eliminated all iframes/frames.

ALSO I disabled all extensions. And it still kept happening.

Edit: Disabling javascript had no effect on this behavior.

Comment: This is not programming related. Should be moved to SuperUser (if applicable) or deleted.

Comment: possible. it is caused by some programming ^_^

Comment: @epochwolf - it is programming related, caused by an autofocus attribute. I've seen it myself in Chrome v25

Comment: Definitely programming related - the off topic mark should be removed. This saved my day!

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the problem was an autofocus element inside a hidden form. Chrome decided that this translates to "sometimes scroll to the middle"